# Possible to embed Tumblr into other website?

Tags: embed, tumblr

I've been able to embed my latest 10 Tumblr posts into a website, but it doesn't include all of the functionality (comments, re-blogs, shares, etc.) of Tumblr. I'm really looking to do that, but I can't find an answer on this anywhere.

I know a lot of programming languages, so I'll take a solution in any language. The website IS a built-from-scratch website, so a Wordpress plugin won't help.

EDIT: Just to confirm (based on comments/questions below), we've followed the API documentation. We've got plenty of APIs working, but this one doesn't. We've tried gems, a Javascript version, the API with oauth and tokens, and more attempts than I can recall.

It's easy to do in Wordpress, and if we were doing it as a subdomain of a site, that would be possible. But the client (pro-bono) wants it embedded on a page that does lots of other things. Maybe there's a Javascript library we don't know about? Some other secret means of doing it? But the API (at least with available documentation) isn't working. Heck, even if you could direct us to a site where someone is using Tumblr embedded on a non-Wordpress/Tumblr website, that would be helpful. We could inspect the code.

We've got Twitter, Google Maps, and plenty of other APIs working. I swear we aren't idiots, and the answer to this isn't as easy as it appears.

THANKS!

Comment: what have You tried so far? I think, You should try checking the official [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) first and getting more or less familiar with it.

Comment: We did that (the API), but it isn't a customizable option--not like so many other API's. We've put it in an iframe now, and that seems to be the best solution. Thanks, to anyone who considered answering.

Comment: Just to clarify, for other users, that the API provides all the functionality the OP requires. Comments and shares are a third party resources and needed to be added elsewhere.

Comment: @mikedidthis to enable reblogs and likes she'd have to use oauth, right? I was asked about it once and we ended up just building a Tumblr theme (thankfully) to avoid that

Comment: We've used the API developer tools. They don't work in any browser. We've had oauth, the tokens, etc. We've gotten what looks like JSON data and doesn't work like JSON. We can't use Tumblr as a website--it's supposed to be part of it. We can't use Wordpress. This is a website built from scratch using Ruby, Javascript, etc.

We have plenty of API's we are using successfully. It's only the Tumblr API that isn't doing what it should be, as @mikedidthis suggests. We KNOW this should be easy and should be easy to sort out, but it just isn't.

Comment: @bfred.it Yes. `oauth` would be required for anything that interacts for the Tumblr servers, such as likes etc.

Comment: @TaraRubyJS Sorry, I wasn't trying to imply you were idiots, please don't think that. My comment was for others. The API works, I have used it many times. Indeed, you don't get properly formatted `JSON` in your response, but its more than possible to use the API to replicate a Tumblr site. If I get chance, I will post a quick example / repo.

Comment: I understand you are angry. But if you want a solution here, you should post the code that you tried (minimal example), tell us what happened and where is the obstacle. It is more likely that you get a good answer this way.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a clear example on how to use the JSON, check this link, it helped me tons:
http://janzheng.com/2013/06/tumblr_integration.html